# How do I keep elements' original size and keep them inside the paper when the paper resizes?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am implementing a UML diagram, the paper gets resized on window resize, I need the classes to stay the same size and stay inside the paper.

The documentation for `paper.scaleContentToFit(opt)` says

> The function accepts an object with additional settings

so I imagined that I can provide several different options from the list, and tried using `paper.scaleContentToFit({padding: 20, minScaleX: 1, minScaleY: 1, maxScaleX: 1 , maxScaleY: 1})` but that only keeps the size of the classes. If I use only `paper.scaleContentToFit({padding: 20})` the classes stay inside the paper but they change size.

So how can I keep the classes' original size (prevent their resize) and keep their location inside the paper when the window (and with that the paper) gets resized?

Edit:

The paper is defined as so:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    gridSize: 1,
    model: graph,
    defaultConnector: { name: 'jumpover' },
    interactive: {arrowheadMove : false },
    restrictTranslate: true
});
```

And this how I tried handling the scaling:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //if I use only this, the classes stay inside the paper but they get resized
    paper.scaleContentToFit();
    
    //if I use only this, the classes keep the original size but they stay outside the window
    paper.scaleContentToFit({minScaleX: 1, minScaleY: 1, maxScaleX: 1 , maxScaleY: 1});
};
```

If I resize the window while using the `scaleContentToFit` with scale parameters provided, it looks like this (and it doesn't move even slightly):

[Class remains outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1CZU.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "stay inside the paper"? The `scaleContentToFit` makes sure the entire content is wrapped within the paper.
What if you define the paper size relatively to its container i.e. `const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({ width: '100%', height: '100%' });`?

Comment: I already have the paper defined like that. And I mean the class actually remains outside the paper, it doesn't change the position. I have added some more info to the post and added a screenshot. Let me know if you need any more info.